# How to copy data automatically once certain data is input in Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to copy certain amounts of data in Microsoft Excel 2010. I have 2 different sheets, i.e. "Master" and "Delivery". In the "Master" sheet, I am making a unique set of ids by concatenating two different cells. These unique ids may or may not exist in the "Delivery" sheet.

I would like to copy certain cells (transport name and d.o.d) automatically for those ids that exists in both "Master" and "Delivery" sheets. Those in the master sheet that do not exist in the delivery sheet should be display "#N/A". Perhaps there are some formulas in the excel that may be able to solve the problem.

Example of the sheets:

**Master sheet**

```
job no      no.      desc      unique id    id in delivery  transport name  d.o.d

1acf23    452036     pen      1acf23452036      Y

1acf23    786952     disc     1acf23786952      Y   

1acf25    786952     disc     1acf25786952      N   

2rfg45    462230     box 1    2rfg45462230      Y   

3rfg45    415789     eraser   3rfg45415789      Y
```

**Delivery Sheet**

```
d.o.d   transport name  job no  no  desc    unique id   id in master

01.08.14    brand1  1acf23  452036  pen     1acf23452036    Y

02.07.14    brand1  1acf23  869632  file    1acf23869632    N

20.03.13    brand1  1acf23  786952  disc    1acf23786952    Y

16.06.14    brand1  1acf23  999021  cutter  1acf23999021    N

17.08.13    brand3  2rfg45  462230  box 1   2rfg45462230    Y

01.01.14    brand2  3rfg45  415789  eraser  3rfg45415789    Y

09.05.14    brand3  2rfg45  415789  eraser  2rfg45415789    N

09.05.14    brand3  2rfg45  462230  box 1   2rfg45462230    Y

01.01.14    brand2  1acf23  263246  pencil  1acf23263246    Y

09.05.14    brand3  5thy12  102364  casing  5thy12102364    Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have your columns right.

For transport name in Master:

```
=INDEX(Delivery!B:B,MATCH(Master!D2,Delivery!F:F,0))
```

and for d.o.d

```
=INDEX(Delivery!A:A,MATCH(Master!D2,Delivery!F:F,0))
```

Greetings

Axel

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Excel function vlookup. You'll probably want to use the flag that makes it look for exact matches only.

Comment: VLOOKUP can not look to the left, just to the right.